# Android http Tunnel using VpnService

Tags: java, android, http, proxy, vpn

I'm trying to redirect the whole android network traffic through HTTP Tunnel, and there is no tutorial or Github Repository on how to do it.

Simply just get the host, port, username, and password from the user and tunnel the whole device to that host programmatically.

I have configured an HTTP-Proxy server with squid, just need a client to connect to it.

I don't want an Open-VPN solution or StrongSwan, this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tunnelguru.toofan) named TOOFAN Tunnel, is doing what exactly I need, but it's only available in some countries and it is not an open-source project.

Just need someone to show me the path or put me in the right direction, I appreciate it in advance.

I know about Android's [VpnServise](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html), and how it redirects the traffic, I just don't know to implement a socket to transfer packets through an HTTP proxy with credentials.

I had built and tested more than 20 repositories but none worked. Some of them are:
[SSLSocks](https://github.com/comp500/SSLSocks), [TunProxy](https://github.com/raise-isayan/TunProxy), [VpnProxy](https://github.com/AoEiuV020/VpnProxy), [SmartProxy](https://github.com/zxc111/SmartProxy), [NetDroidProxy](https://github.com/zeeying/NetDroidProxy), [LocalVPN](https://github.com/hexene/LocalVPN), [xSocks-android](https://github.com/lparam/xSocks-android), [prox](https://github.com/xingrz/prox).

Comment: For testing you can use `network.proxy.ssl` (that must be using `CONNECT`) configuration on Firefox Android app (though not system-wide testing). SSLSocks is `stunnel` and xSocks-android looks like SOCKS5, both won't work with squid. What about the rest? Can you please share your experience how/why those didn't work for you, particularly TunProxy? Note: I'm not a developer but looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this library I made, it should allow you to do just about anything with Proxys or what not. I know its a very late response, however I hope it will help someone...

https://github.com/DrBrad/Android-VPN-to-Socket

https://github.com/DrBrad/JTun2Socks

The simplest way to do so is by creating a DNS proxy for UDP packets and a TCP server for TCP packets. You must manipulate the TCP packets to direct towards the new TCP server. You can pull the host and port by creating a simple nat session.